# Rössler attractor, Convergence of box counting to estimate the fractal dimension

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, limits-and-convergence, fractals, chaos

At the moment I want to estimate the fractal dimension of the [Rössler attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ssler_attractor). I have written a program, which is counting the boxes hitted N(ɛ) (with ɛ := side length of boxes) by a trajectory on the attractor. The trajectory is calculated numerically. So for a rising number of iterations, N(ɛ) is rising, like it is shown in the following graph (for ɛ = 1/128, horizontal axis is for iterations, vertical axis for N(ɛ)).

Graph for N(ɛ) against iterations:

[image: graph]

The thing is, that the Graph is not converging, even if I run it for 50*10^6 iterations. There is a similar work for the Lorentz attractor, written by Mark J.McGuinness called "[The Fractal Dimension of the Lorentz attractor](https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(83)90052-X)" published in the Physics Letters Volume 99A number 1 on the 14 November 1983. Since the Lorentz attractor is similar to the Rössler attractor, you could get a good orientation from this work. In the paper they have the same problem for the Lorentz attractor and they guess the convergence to be algebraic and not logarithmic.

**Question**
What is known about the (algebraic ?) convergence of N(ɛ) (boxes bitted by a trajectory on the attractor) for strange attractors ?

Comment: I think all that McGuinness means by algebraic convergence is that the difference to the "true value" decays as a power law, see eq. 5. I suppose to apply this to your problem you may try showing your data on a log-log plot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot . In any case, I think this site is not quite right for your question and it would be better served on math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: In my opinion, @Chopin has clearly been doing some *research* and he has encountered a difficulty. The given problem does not seem to be trivial, and is definitely of research level. It's not Grothendieck-like algebraic geometry, but it is still research.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer, this helps me.  I  have posted the question on math.stackexchange, but until now i've got no answer, so i posted it here.

Comment: @Chopin Perhaps you can edit your post to include a link to the post on MSE. Also, reading your question again and in light of Alex M.'s comment I think there could be an interesting research question here but you haven't made it explicit. In particular, I don't see any question marks, only a few things that you say you don't know anything about. Consider editing so that there is one or a few clear mathematical questions. For instance, you might ask something like "what is known about the convergence of box-counting algorithms for fractal dimension estimation for strange attractors?"

Comment: Crossposted on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594638/roessler-attractor-convergence-of-box-counting-to-estimate-the-fractal-dimensio

Comment: @j.c thank you for the tips, I will add up a research question. And thanks Alex M. for adding up the crosspost.